# What is the syntax error in this xquery script?

Tags: xquery

I'm a beginner to XQuery, trying to do some simple exercises to learn it.  But this latest query I'm trying to put together refuses to run, giving me a syntax error.

This is my XQuery:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD><TITLE>Alphabetical Cities Lists</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY>
{
  for $indcode in (65 to 70)
  let $indlet := codepoints-to-string($indcode)
  return 
     <H1> {$indlet} LIST </H1>
     {
       for $cit in doc("mydoc.xml")/CITIES/ENTITY
       where starts-with($cit/NAME,$indlet)
       order by $cit/NAME
       return <LI>{$cit/NAME}</LI>
     }
     </OL>
} 
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

And this is a subset of my XML file mydoc.xml:

```
<CITIES>
  <ENTITY>
    <NAME>Hastings</NAME>
    <CITYCOD>230</CITYCOD>
    <CNTYCOD>01</CNTYCOD>
  </ENTITY>
  <ENTITY>
    <NAME>Tilden</NAME>
    <CITYCOD>487</CITYCOD>
    <CNTYCOD>02</CNTYCOD>
  </ENTITY>
  <ENTITY>
    <NAME>Alliance</NAME>
    <CITYCOD>008</CITYCOD>
    <CNTYCOD>07</CNTYCOD>
  </ENTITY>
  <ENTITY>
    <NAME>Hemingford</NAME>
    <CITYCOD>236</CITYCOD>
    <CNTYCOD>07</CNTYCOD>
  </ENTITY>
  <ENTITY>
    <NAME>Ainsworth</NAME>
    <CITYCOD>003</CITYCOD>
    <CNTYCOD>09</CNTYCOD>
  </ENTITY>
  <ENTITY>
    <NAME>Kearney</NAME>
    <CITYCOD>269</CITYCOD>
    <CNTYCOD>10</CNTYCOD>
  </ENTITY>
  <ENTITY>
    <NAME>Oakland</NAME>
    <CITYCOD>358</CITYCOD>
    <CNTYCOD>11</CNTYCOD>
  </ENTITY>
  <ENTITY>
    <NAME>Eagle</NAME>
    <CITYCOD>159</CITYCOD>
    <CNTYCOD>13</CNTYCOD>
  </ENTITY>
</CITIES>
```

What I want it to do is print out a simple HTML document with several lists of these city names, broken out by the letter they start with (A to F).

But when I try running this out on [this site](http://try.zorba-xquery.com/), it gives me this error:

**Query: <>, line 9, column 6: [XPST0003] syntax error, unexpected "'{'", expecting "'}'"**

I have no idea why it says that.  I've checked and checked, but my curly braces all seem properly matched.  Can anyone see what the problem is?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common mistake.

You need to place a , between the `<H1>` and `<OL>` nodes.

A single node is an XQuery expression (as are multiple nodes inside a direct element constructor).  The return expression must be an expression.  In this case you want to return two nodes.  Each node is a single item and so in order to return them both you need to concatenate the two nodes in a sequence.

The query would look like this:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD><TITLE>Alphabetical Cities Lists</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY>
{
  for $indcode in (65 to 70)
  let $indlet := codepoints-to-string($indcode)
  return 
     (<H1> {$indlet} LIST </H1>,
     <OL>
     {
       for $cit in doc("mydoc.xml")/CITIES/ENTITY
       where starts-with($cit/NAME,$indlet)
       order by $cit/NAME
       return <LI>{$cit/NAME}</LI>
     }
     </OL>)
} 
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a <OL> before the { on line 9.

So it should be:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD><TITLE>Alphabetical Cities Lists</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY>
{
  for $indcode in (65 to 70)
  let $indlet := codepoints-to-string($indcode)
  return 
     <H1> {$indlet} LIST </H1>
     <OL>
     {
       for $cit in doc("mydoc.xml")/CITIES/ENTITY
       where starts-with($cit/NAME,$indlet)
       order by $cit/NAME
       return <LI>{$cit/NAME}</LI>
     }
     </OL>
} 
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Thanks, you're right, I did.  But that still leaves the syntax error.