# Escape characters in XQuery

Tags: html, xquery

I have an html div line in my .xql file as:

```
<div id="imageBlock" class="a-row" style="height:386.6666666666667px;">
```

And it keeps throwing error. I think saxon wants me to remove ';' from the end but its not gonna work if i remove it. So is there a way of escaping semicolons in XQuery. There are more than 500 semicolon in my xquery above is just one line. I tried this

```
<div id="imageBlock" class="a-row" style="height:386.6666666666667px{\;}"> 

AND

<div id="imageBlock" class="a-row" style="height:386.6666666666667px{\};">
```

Both doesn't work. :(

Comment: Your assumption is wrong. `;` is not a special character in XML and does not have to be escaped. If you want help, you might want to post the actual error message, your XQuery code and input data.

Comment: @dirkk - It just says static error next to it and once removed it goes and catches the next one

Comment: I don't know what's wrong as you don't supply more information, e.g. your actual query or your actual error. But I just tested your snippet in Saxon (with the semicolon) and it caused no trouble at all, as expected.

Comment: Yeah, we need more information about what system is giving you the error (name, version), the error itself, its col/row, etc.  Throwing a guess out: Have you closed the tag with a </div>?

Comment: *Why* do you "think saxon wants me to remove ';' from the end"?  That seems very unlikely.  It is far more likely (I hope you won't mind my saying this) that you are misinterpreting what Saxon is telling you.  If you provide details, and enough code and data to allow the problem to be reproduced, someone here may be able to help.  Otherwise, good luck to you and you're on your own.

Comment: Like others have stated, you need to provide more details. What is the actual error? My first guess is that you actually have a literal `&` that should be escaped as `&amp;`. It "goes and catches the next one" because the `;` is seen as the end of an entity reference. Either that or your `div` tag isn't closed (like @joewiz said). At a minimum, add the actual error to your question. Ideally, also add enough code/data for us to reproduce (like C.M. S-McQ said).

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the syntax error in this xquery script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086441/what-is-the-syntax-error-in-this-xquery-script)